# Windows 11: Change background of inactive task bar icons

Tags: windows-11, taskbar, regedit

I would like to change the background of opened elements in the taskbar making it the same design as when I hover inactive elements. Now that Windows 11 has the ungroup feature in the taskbar, I think that this would make the look even nicer.

Here’s the idea:

[image: ![Taskbar idea]

Is there a registry modification or any other way of achieving this?

Comment: It may be how you set up your themes and backgrounds.  My Windows 11 system shows what you want already.

Comment: So you have a background with border around your open but inactive apps in the taskbar? I’ve looked into the preferences but couldn’t find a setting for this. (Also no screenshots showing what I want.)

Comment: No. the icons (inactive or not) use the taskbar background for the icon background.

Comment: I have noticed that my previous screenshot was not correct, I have updated it to clarify the idea. What I would like to have is the border and background colour for open but unselected apps. In my screenshot, Firefox is open and selected whereas Signal is active but not selected.

Comment: What does "active" mean exactly? Not minimized, or?

Comment: That the app is open (might or might not be minimized). As opposed to the other icons in the examples (Office and File Explorer), which are just shortcuts in the taskbar. Sorry for the confusing terminology.